# Does a function have to be defined at $z_0$ in order to have a Taylor/Laurent Series $\textit{about}$ $z_0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does a function have to be defined at $z_0$ in order to have a Taylor/Laurent Series *about* $z_0$ ?

---

EDIT:
I just came across something called a removable singularity, which we have not yet covered in my complex analysis course, I think that this may have something to do with my problem.

Comment: No. For example, $f(z) = 1/z$ is its own Laurent series about $z_0 = 0$.

Comment: To have a Taylor series around $x_0$ all the derivatives have to exist at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes for Taylor series and no for Laurent series. Technically the Taylor series of a function $f$ at $z_0$ is the series

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0}{n!}(z-z_0)^n$$

where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative. In particular, we see that $f^{(0)}(z_0)=f(z_0)$.

That said, the Laurent series is defined by a contour integral around a circle with center $z_0$--in particular, $f$ needn't be defined at $z_0$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you. Fixed.